# How to send only 1 email instead of 2 email to new users on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

On my WordPress website when I use this code it sends an email to the new user upon registration and it's very confusing because the ultimate outcome I want to achieve is to send them an email that their account has been verified and is able to login to the website.

And in this case, it sends an email when the user registered to the website and when I update their role it sends them the same email as well....

Is there a solution to avoid sending emails to new users upon registration?

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
    $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $to = $user_info->user_email; 
    $subject = "Calendar WebApp";
    $message = "Hello " .$user_info->display_name . "\n\nThank you for registering with CalendarWebApp!\n ".$site_url." \n\nProceed to the website when your role is WINSPO\n\n"."Your current role is ".strtoupper($new_role);
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);

    if ( strtotime ( $user_info->user_registered) < strtotime ('-30 minutes') ) {
        //send email
    }

}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the action? `remove_action('set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10);`

Comment: Hi @fubar so do I replace the "add_action" code to "remove_Action"? and if so what does it does because I'm new to this PHP coding

Comment: Hi, @fubar I tried using your "remove_action" code and right now it doesn't send any email to the new users at all.

Comment: That depends. Is the code you posted from a plugin or something you added to your `functions.php` file?

Comment: @fubar is a code added to the functions.php file using the code snippet pluggins

Comment: If it's your own code, then you can simply omit the `add_action()` call, and remove the `user_role_update()` function entirely if it's no longer being used.

Comment: @fubar alright thank you!! I will give it a try and update here if there are any issues!